# Does Mighty Mighty Missile Have The Same Maps As The GBA Che Chu Rocket?

Tags: game-boy-advance, chuchu-rocket, mighty-mighty-missile

Mighty Mighty Missile is a homebrew game that was released on the Sega CD in 2004, and it appears to have incorporated many game play elements and assess from Sonic Team's Chu Chu Rocket, specifically the one released for the Game Boy Advanced. I was wondering if the maps associated with Mighty Mighty Missile are original or also happen to be ripped from the GBA?